# How to install debugging tools for windows 32 bits side by side with 64 bits on a 64 bits OS?

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg

I have a 64 bit Windows 2008R2 VM, where I installed Debugging tools for Windows 64 bit from the SDK. Now I wish to install the 32 bits and even downloaded the respective ISO - GRMSDK_EN_DVD.iso from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8442

However, the damn thing thinks there is nothing to install, because the 64 bits is already installed.

How can I still install it?

### Edit

OK, I uninstalled the 64 bit version. Now, it fails to install with this lovely message:

```
Setup could not find the file WinSDK_amd64\WinSDK_amd64.msi at any of the specified source locations E:\Setup
```

Microsoft support site claims that I am probably trying to install a wrong architecture. But the ISO file name is GRMSDK_EN_DVD.iso and http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8442 says it is for x86.

If I cannot install x86 on a 64 bits OS, then how do I get the 32 bits windbg installed on my 64 bits OS?

Comment: From what I vaugely remember, the sdk would leave a copy of the msi of both 32 and 64 bit debugging tools somewhere inside the installation folder. You could directly run the 32 bit msi from there.

Comment: The MSI executed by the Windows Insatller service. Make shure that drive E: is also visible to it. Network drives ans SUBST drive will not work.

Comment: It is a CD drive mounted by Daemon Tools. Visible to all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found this good Samaritan - http://rxwen.blogspot.ca/2010/04/standalone-windbg-v6120002633.html

Thank you, thank you, thank you.

Comment: Note, these versions are quite old and aren't suitable for Win8 debugging

Comment: in the comments someone mentioned this: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/debugtoolswindows

Answer (score 4):

The Windows SDK for Windows 7 (for example) ISO image contains the installers under `Setup\WinSDKDebuggingTools` and `Setup\WinSDKDebuggingTools_amd64` folders.

This applies to both 32 bit or 64 bit SDK ISO, and you don't need to install the SDK itself.

The Windows 8 SDK ISO changed a little bit here by putting the debugger installers under `Installers` folder, `X64 Debuggers And Tools-x64_en-us.msi` and `X86 Debuggers And Tools-x86_en-us.msi`. After installing both, you can find them under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Debuggers`

Comment: Yes, I did install Windows 8 SDK first and found both debugging tools there. However, do you know the version of DbgHelp.dll that comes with this SDK? It is 6.2.9200.16386 - ancient history. At first I did not believe it, after all Windows 8. But go ahead and see for yourself.

Comment: I think that version is new. They did something weird with the versioning of Debugging Tools for Windows.

Comment: Why would they do something like this? A reference, please.

Comment: A couple of years back the version was 6.12.x.x and 6.11.x.x. Even further back it was 6.4.7.2.

Comment: 6.2.9200 is Windows 8 RTM build.  I guess the debugging tools was redone to be built as part of Windows or something.

Comment: @mark who says 6.2.9200.16386 is ancient? Without a release notes for reference, I think you made a wrong assumption. Check its "Date modified" and you can see July 2012, which must be the latest.

Comment: Guys, does it seems logical to you to change the version of a dll in such a way? I mean there are tools out there which check the version to see if the existing DbgHelp.dll is good. I know of one at least. These tools plainly reject the newest DbgHelp.dll claiming it was too old. Even if this DbgHelp.dll is the newest.

Comment: Only Microsoft guys can give you an official explanation on why they decided to handle version number in this way. You can do nothing but accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Previously Microsoft posted the installers directly on their website; this was so much easier than the current method.  Now you have to [download the SDK installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852363), select both debuggers, let them download, then figure out where they got downloaded to and copy them off somewhere for easy access in the future.  The ISOs are overkill unless you want the rest of the SDK components as well.

Comment: Which "both debuggers" ? I cannot see any references to two debuggers. Please, elaborate.

Comment: Unfortunately the SDK installer is temporarily unavailable right now, but if I recall correctly you can choose to download a debugging package.  This will download both the x86 and x64 windbg installers.

Comment: Ok, it's back online now.  So download the installer, choose the "Download for installation on a separate computer" option, select only the Debugging Tools for Windows feature, and start the download.  When it's done you will have MSIs for both flavors of the debugging tools in the Installers subfolder of the download location.